# How to generate PDF file from HTTP response body, using axios in react native mobile app

Tags: react-native, http, parsing, pdf, axios

I'm calling a third party endpoint, which returns a pdf file directly, not an access url or anything of the kind. I need to parse that pdf and display it to the user, I do not have access to the endpoint nor can modify the response.

Here is the axios call to the endpoint, the .then and .catch are like that in order to try and visualize the responses:

`await axios .get( 'endpoint_url', { headers: { Authorization:` Bearer ${authToken}`, }, }, ) .then(response => { console.log(JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 2)); }) .catch(error => { console.error(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2)); });`

This is the response I'm getting from calling that request, or part of it since the response data is too long and is not entirely shown on console:

`u001d<z|��욺2:If�\f��{tl��]�[v�o�]��Dj��\u0012{�o���x�g����\rl\u001cO\u00071�wL�\u001c�w�Ά\u00033���-�L����\u0010�c�\u0002\"�NӠ��+�4�Nb�n��}�\u0016\u0014�4�\u0018,�i\u0016\u0006c���+�4��<M�\u0016��4�\u0002����'O\u0012�`��\bO�2!DX&O2�T�R+��$���Dv*M�L�<�J�<�i�������8�֣f�ľ���N��;\u001d1����W��j/�ŶN��\u000b�:�h�eS� z������}����m�1�,�'��\u001e�}��ľc�o���ާ�G�G��K��l�?���i�Z��\u0011g��\b�Y\u0005=�׳\�J��ӳ�ҳ�ҳ�'��g\u0001���\u0011�ڠwͅ\u0013M�M��ȯS�rkz\u0007�y=9���\r-�ڍ�ʓ`���9�{�9\u0011t�^���Kا�\u000b��֥��\u001e�Y�ٓ�%\u0003�=��!���WC���>�����Q���\n7��?�����%.��  �p\u0011����\u0007�U��0~��b�\u0014z���8��oC�ь숑�)R\u0014[\u0012R\\\u0015�i������ڢ���k�緱D\u000e[\u0004\u000bkĺ��c\u0004\u0014\u0005c&�N�0~7�R4<,��\u0017\\��la�\u001eV��q0�@�¢��3�.\u0016Y�̉Y\u0016����*+�Rc�����\u0000]�5\nendstream\nendobj\n21 0 obj\n<</Descent -210/CapHeight 716//StemV 80/Type/FontDescriptor/FontFile2 20 0 R/Flags 32/FontBBox[-664 -324 2000 1005]/FontName/HFKBLG+ArialMT/ItalicAngle 0/Ascent 728>>\nendobj\n5 0 obj\n<</Subtype/TrueType/FirstChar 32/Type/Font/BaseFont/HFKBLG+ArialMT/FontDescriptor 21 0 R/Encoding<</Type/Encoding/Differences[32/space 36/dollar/percent 40/parenleft/parenright 43/plus/comma/hyphen/period/slash/zero/one/two/three/four/five/six/seven/eight/nine/colon 64/at/A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P/Q/R/S/T/U/V/W 90/Z 97/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j 108/l/m/n/o/p/q/r/s/t/u/v/w/x/y/z 187/guillemotright 193/Aacute 225/aacute 233/eacute 237/iacute 241/ntilde 243/oacute 250/uacute]>>/LastChar 250/Widths[277 0 0 0 556 889 0 0 333 333 0 583 277 333 277 277 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 277 0 0 0 0 0 1015 666 666 722 722 666 610 777 722 277 500 666 556 833 722 777 666 777 722 666 610 722 666 943 0 0 610 0 0 0 0 0 0 556 556 500 556 556 277 556 556 222 222 0 222 833 556 556 556 556 333 500 277 556 500 722 500 500 500 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 556 0 0 0 0 0 666 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 556 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 556 0 0 0 277 0 0 0 556 0 556 0 0 0 0 0 0 556]>>\nendobj\n8 0 obj\n<</Kids[1 0 R 9 0 R 13 0 R]/Type/Pages/Count 3>>\nendobj\n22 0 obj\n<</Names[(JR_PAGE_ANCHOR_0_1) 15 0 R(JR_PAGE_ANCHOR_0_2) 16 0 R(JR_PAGE_ANCHOR_0_3) 17 0 R]>>\nendobj\n23 0 obj\n<</Dests 22 0 R>>\nendobj\n24 0 obj\n<</Names 23 0 R/Type/Catalog/Pages 8 0 R/ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/AppDefault>>>>\nendobj\n25 0 obj\n<</ModDate(D:20240116183518Z)/Creator(JasperReports \\(em_k_jrp_condiciones_441_mcr\\))/CreationDate(D:20240116183518Z)/Producer(iText 2.1.4 \\(by lowagie.com\\))>>\nendobj\nxref\n0 26\n0000000000 65535 f \n0000035835 00000 n \n0000065081 00000 n \n0000000015 00000 n \n0000095153 00000 n \n0000130839 00000 n \n0000017277 00000 n \n0000031562 00000 n \n0000131954 00000 n \n0000063812 00000 n \n0000036121 00000 n \n0000036338 00000 n \n0000058679 00000 n \n0000064704 00000 n \n0000064112 00000 n \n0000064972 00000 n \n0000065008 00000 n \n0000065044 00000 n \n0000065169 00000 n \n0000094962 00000 n \n0000096217 00000 n \n0000130657 00000 n \n0000132018 00000 n \n0000132128 00000 n \n0000132162 00000 n \n0000132267 00000 n \ntrailer\n<</Info 25 0 R/ID [<3121f17e71cf81763b53e99f59be3a14><279c242a1ed3b1a64218007b9a38aa92>]/Root 24 0 R/Size 26>>\nstartxref\n132444\n%%EOF\n", "_url": "endpoint_url", "_timedOut": false, "_trackingName": "unknown", "_incrementalEvents": false, "_performanceLogger": { "_timespans": { "network_XMLHttpRequest_endpoint_url": { "startTime": 332813.849083, "endTime": 334864.79304, "totalTime": 2050.9439570000395 }, "network_XMLHttpRequest_endpoint_url: { "startTime": 334951.501475, "endTime": 337555.668931, "totalTime": 2604.1674559999956 }, "network_XMLHttpRequest_endpoint_url": { "startTime": 337638.005393, "endTime": 345447.827197, "totalTime": 7809.821803999948 }, "network_XMLHttpRequest_endpoint_url": { "startTime": 345555.128839, "endTime": 346216.506761, "totalTime": 661.3779220000142 }, "network_XMLHttpRequest_endpoint_url": { "startTime": 418717.350887, "endTime": 419081.171069, "totalTime": 363.82018199999584 }, "network_XMLHttpRequest_endpoint_url": { "startTime": 419095.380466, "endTime": 431738.382299, "totalTime": 12643.001832999988 }, "network_XMLHttpRequest_endpoint_url": { "startTime": 785574.027414, "endTime": 786044.930733, "totalTime": 470.90331900003366 }, "network_XMLHttpRequest_endpoint_url": { "startTime": 786053.318968, "endTime": 792971.590102, "totalTime": 6918.271134000039 } }, "_extras": {}, "_points": { "initializeCore_start": 331398.129653, "initializeCore_end": 331713.446093 }, "_pointExtras": {}, "_closed": false, "_isLoggingForWebPerformance": false }, "responseHeaders": { "content-type": "application/pdf", "cache-control": "no-cache", "server": "", "access-control-allow-origin": "*", "x-aspnetmvc-version": "", "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000", "content-length": "133116", "pragma": "no-cache", "date": "Tue, 16 Jan 2024 18:51:02 GMT", "content-disposition": "inline; filename=\"filename.pdf\"", "expires": "-1" }, "_requestId": null, "_headers": { "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "authorization": "Bearer authToken" }, "_responseType": "", "_sent": true, "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": { "content-type": "application/pdf", "cache-control": "no-cache", "server": "", "access-control-allow-origin": "*", "x-aspnetmvc-version": "", "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000", "content-length": "133116", "pragma": "no-cache", "date": "Tue, 16 Jan 2024 18:51:02 GMT", "content-disposition": "inline; filename=\"filename.pdf\"", "expires": "-1" }, "_subscriptions": [], "responseURL": "endpoint_url" } }`

I've tried using different solutions posted here, like adding `responseType: 'blob'` to the request configuration, or creating a file from a blob, though in mobile it is not working as suggested for a web application. I need to generate a file from that response, and be able to use it to display, download, or any other possible user interaction, and plan to use the [react-native-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf) to handle the file once I have it.